# select rows mysql order by custom value From the bottom of the table to the top of the table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want Last eight posts if productgroup='برنامه نویسی' And the results that they have subject="css" Have a higher priority

[image: schema table]

**this is my code :**

```
$query = "SELECT productcode FROM (SELECT * FROM product ORDER BY productcode DESC) secondTab

WHERE productgroup='برنامه نویسی' ORDER BY FIELD(subject,'css') DESC limit 8";
```

But get result From the top of the table to the bottom of the table:
6
7
8
10
14
20
34
2

Comment: Please explain the logic you want to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ORDER BY` clause inside the subquery is useless.
Sort the results like this:

```
SELECT productcode 
FROM product 
WHERE productgroup = 'برنامه نویسی' 
ORDER BY FIELD(subject,'css') DESC, productcode DESC 
LIMIT 8
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want product code 21 to be last, use two `order by` keys:

```
order by (productcode = 21) asc,   -- put it last
         productcode desc
```

MySQL treats boolean values as integers in a numeric context, with `0` for false and `1` for true.  Hence, "false" is ordered (using `ASC`) before true values.